# Sort CSV File by Numerical Values

Tags: python, csv, sorting, operator-keyword

So for a Homework task i have to make a program that sorts scores like a leader board and i cant figure out how to sort it in descending order.

I will send the rest of my code if that helps, any help would be appreciated.

Forgot to mention CSV file looks like this:
NAME, SCORE

I have Seen many questions on here about this and none of them seem to work with mine.

```
with open('names.csv', 'a', newline='') as names:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(names)
    csvWriter.writerow([name, int(score)])

with open('names.csv', 'r') as names:
    csvReader = csv.reader(names)
    csv1 = csv.reader(names, delimiter='.')
    sort = sorted(csv1, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    csv_writer = csv.writer(names, delimiter='.')
    for name in csvReader:
        print(' '.join(name))
```

no error message or results, just an exit code

Comment: Use pandas library. If you can't that means that you have to learn how to do it, not ask someone to do it for you because, as you said, it's homework. Clue: read the csv file and make a dictionary with the names as the key and the score as the value and learn how to sort a dictionary in python.

Answer (score 0):

See here for reading a csv into dataframe

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

and here for sorting it

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with your code here, i'll try to break it down.. I don't recommend you jump to pandas just yet. I'm going to assume this is actually writing data.. but you should check "names.csv" to make sure it isn't empty. It looks like this would only write one row. I'm also not sure why you set `newline=''`, I probably wouldn't do that here.. though i'm not sure it will matter to `csv.writer`.

```
with open('names.csv', 'a', newline='') as names:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(names)
    csvWriter.writerow([name, int(score)])
```

usually you would have a loop inside a statement like this:

```
my_list = [("Bob", "2"), ("Alice", "1")]

with open('names.csv', 'a') as names:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(names)
    for name, score in my_list:
        csvWriter.writerow([name, int(score)])
```

You make two csv readers here.. i'm not sure why. The second one uses "." as it's delimiter.. you haven't specified a delimiter when you wrote the csv, so it would actually have the standard delimiter with is a comma ",". `csvReader` would use this by default, but `csv1` will attempt to split on periods and not do so well.

```
with open('names.csv', 'r') as names:
    csvReader = csv.reader(names)
    csv1 = csv.reader(names, delimiter='.')
```

You shouldn't use "sort" as a variable name.. it's the name of a common method. But that won't actually break anything here.. you create a new sorted version of `csv1` but you actually run your for loop on `csvReader` which hasn't changed since you set it above. You also create `csv_writer` with `names` with is open for reading, not writing. but you don't use it anyway.
`itemgetter` is looking at index `0`, which would be the names from your writer.. if you want to sort by score use `1`.

```
    sort = sorted(csv1, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    csv_writer = csv.writer(names, delimiter='.')
    for name in csvReader:
        print(' '.join(name))
```

I think this might be more what you're going for.. with my example list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv
import operator

my_list = [("Bob", "2"), ("Alice", "1")]

with open('names.csv', 'a') as names:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(names)
    for name, score in my_list:
        csvWriter.writerow([name, int(score)])

with open('names.csv', 'r') as names:
    csvReader = csv.reader(names)
    sorted_reader = sorted(csvReader, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    for name, score in sorted_reader:
         print(name, score)
```

Output:

```
Alice 1
Bob 2
```

Since you want it to look "like a leaderboard" you probably want a different sort though.. you want to reverse it and actually use the integer values of the score column (so that 100 will appear above 2, for example).

```
    sorted_reader = sorted(csvReader, key=lambda row: int(row[1]), reverse=True)
```